# udev rule not working on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi, udev

I'm trying to separate some keyboards so they're not read by Qt on a Raspberry Pi. I'm using a `udev` rule to do so, but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm trying to direct `/dev/input/event3` into `/dev/input/ccreader` and `/dev/input/event4` into `/dev/input/barcode`. Could anyone point me in the right direction? I'll post all info below:

Contents of /etc/udev/rules.d/99-com.rules (IMPORTANT 2 AT TOP):

```
KERNEL=="event*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0801", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0001", MODE:="0660", NAME:="input/ccreader%n"
KERNEL=="event*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="05fe", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1010", MODE:="0660", NAME:="input/barcode%n"

SUBSYSTEM=="input", GROUP="input", MODE="0660"
SUBSYSTEM=="i2c-dev", GROUP="i2c", MODE="0660"
SUBSYSTEM=="spidev", GROUP="spi", MODE="0660"
SUBSYSTEM=="bcm2835-gpiomem", GROUP="gpio", MODE="0660"

SUBSYSTEM=="gpio*", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c '\
    chown -R root:gpio /sys/class/gpio && chmod -R 770 /sys/class/gpio;\
    chown -R root:gpio /sys/devices/virtual/gpio && chmod -R 770 /sys/devices/virtual/gpio;\
    chown -R root:gpio /sys$devpath && chmod -R 770 /sys$devpath\
'"

KERNEL=="ttyAMA[01]", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c '\
    ALIASES=/proc/device-tree/aliases; \
    if cmp -s $ALIASES/uart0 $ALIASES/serial0; then \
        echo 0;\
    elif cmp -s $ALIASES/uart0 $ALIASES/serial1; then \
        echo 1; \
    else \
        exit 1; \
    fi\
'", SYMLINK+="serial%c"

KERNEL=="ttyS0", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c '\
    ALIASES=/proc/device-tree/aliases; \
    if cmp -s $ALIASES/uart1 $ALIASES/serial0; then \
        echo 0; \
    elif cmp -s $ALIASES/uart1 $ALIASES/serial1; then \
        echo 1; \
    else \
        exit 1; \
    fi \
'", SYMLINK+="serial%c"
```

---

```
# udevadm info --attribute-walk --name /dev/input/event4
Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

  looking at device '/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/0003:0801:0001.0005/input/input4/event4':
    KERNEL=="event4"
    SUBSYSTEM=="input"
    DRIVER==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/0003:0801:0001.0005/input/input4':
    KERNELS=="input4"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="input"
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{name}=="HID 0801:0001"
    ATTRS{phys}=="usb-3f980000.usb-1.4/input0"
    ATTRS{uniq}==""
    ATTRS{properties}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/0003:0801:0001.0005':
    KERNELS=="0003:0801:0001.0005"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="hid"
    DRIVERS=="hid-generic"
    ATTRS{country}=="00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0':
    KERNELS=="1-1.4:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usbhid"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="03"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="01"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="01"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4':
    KERNELS=="1-1.4"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1.4"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="0801"
    ATTRS{speed}=="12"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="6"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="100mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="80"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0100"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{version}==" 1.10"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="40"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{removable}=="removable"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0001"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1':
    KERNELS=="1-1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="02"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="0424"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="2mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="5"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0200"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="72"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="9514"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1':
    KERNELS=="usb1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="1"
    ATTRS{interface_authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0404"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{serial}=="3f980000.usb"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="26"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 4.4.26-v7+ dwc_otg_hcd"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{product}=="DWC OTG Controller"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb':
    KERNELS=="3f980000.usb"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="platform"
    DRIVERS=="dwc_otg"
    ATTRS{hnp}=="HstNegScs = 0x0"
    ATTRS{srp}=="SesReqScs = 0x1"
    ATTRS{regvalue}=="invalid offset"
    ATTRS{hsic_connect}=="HSIC Connect = 0x1"
    ATTRS{guid}=="GUID = 0x2708a000"
    ATTRS{mode}=="Mode = 0x1"
    ATTRS{srpcapable}=="SRPCapable = 0x1"
    ATTRS{regdump}=="Register Dump"
    ATTRS{gpvndctl}=="GPVNDCTL = 0x00000000"
    ATTRS{ggpio}=="GGPIO = 0x00000000"
    ATTRS{hprt0}=="HPRT0 = 0x00001005"
    ATTRS{wr_reg_test}=="Time to write GNPTXFSIZ reg 10000000 times: 380 msecs (38 jiffies)"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{hcd_frrem}=="HCD Dump Frame Remaining"
    ATTRS{mode_ch_tim_en}=="Mode Change Ready Timer Enable = 0x0"
    ATTRS{gnptxfsiz}=="GNPTXFSIZ = 0x01000306"
    ATTRS{remote_wakeup}=="Remote Wakeup Sig = 0 Enabled = 0 LPM Remote Wakeup = 0"
    ATTRS{busconnected}=="Bus Connected = 0x1"
    ATTRS{hcddump}=="HCD Dump"
    ATTRS{gotgctl}=="GOTGCTL = 0x001c0001"
    ATTRS{spramdump}=="SPRAM Dump"
    ATTRS{grxfsiz}=="GRXFSIZ = 0x00000306"
    ATTRS{gsnpsid}=="GSNPSID = 0x4f54280a"
    ATTRS{gusbcfg}=="GUSBCFG = 0x20001700"
    ATTRS{hptxfsiz}=="HPTXFSIZ = 0x02000406"
    ATTRS{devspeed}=="Device Speed = 0x0"
    ATTRS{fr_interval}=="Frame Interval = 0x1d4c"
    ATTRS{rem_wakeup_pwrdn}==""
    ATTRS{bussuspend}=="Bus Suspend = 0x0"
    ATTRS{buspower}=="Bus Power = 0x1"
    ATTRS{hnpcapable}=="HNPCapable = 0x1"
    ATTRS{rd_reg_test}=="Time to read GNPTXFSIZ reg 10000000 times: 940 msecs (94 jiffies)"
    ATTRS{enumspeed}=="Device Enumeration Speed = 0x1"
    ATTRS{inv_sel_hsic}=="Invert Select HSIC = 0x0"
    ATTRS{regoffset}=="0xffffffff"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc':
    KERNELS=="soc"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="platform"
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform':
    KERNELS=="platform"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

---

```
# udevadm info --attribute-walk --name /dev/input/event3

Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

  looking at device '/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/0003:05FE:1010.0004/input/input3/event3':
    KERNEL=="event3"
    SUBSYSTEM=="input"
    DRIVER==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/0003:05FE:1010.0004/input/input3':
    KERNELS=="input3"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="input"
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{name}=="WIT Electron Company WIT 122-UFS V7.03"
    ATTRS{phys}=="usb-3f980000.usb-1.3/input0"
    ATTRS{uniq}==""
    ATTRS{properties}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/0003:05FE:1010.0004':
    KERNELS=="0003:05FE:1010.0004"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="hid"
    DRIVERS=="hid-generic"
    ATTRS{country}=="21"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0':
    KERNELS=="1-1.3:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usbhid"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="03"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="01"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="01"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3':
    KERNELS=="1-1.3"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1.3"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="05fe"
    ATTRS{speed}=="1.5"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="8"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="5"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="500mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="a0"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0001"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{version}==" 1.10"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="13"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="WIT Electron Company"
    ATTRS{removable}=="removable"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="1010"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{product}=="WIT 122-UFS V7.03"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1':
    KERNELS=="1-1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="02"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="0424"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="2mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="5"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0200"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="72"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="9514"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1':
    KERNELS=="usb1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="1"
    ATTRS{interface_authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0404"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{serial}=="3f980000.usb"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="26"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 4.4.26-v7+ dwc_otg_hcd"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{product}=="DWC OTG Controller"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb':
    KERNELS=="3f980000.usb"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="platform"
    DRIVERS=="dwc_otg"
    ATTRS{hnp}=="HstNegScs = 0x0"
    ATTRS{srp}=="SesReqScs = 0x1"
    ATTRS{regvalue}=="invalid offset"
    ATTRS{hsic_connect}=="HSIC Connect = 0x1"
    ATTRS{guid}=="GUID = 0x2708a000"
    ATTRS{mode}=="Mode = 0x1"
    ATTRS{srpcapable}=="SRPCapable = 0x1"
    ATTRS{regdump}=="Register Dump"
    ATTRS{gpvndctl}=="GPVNDCTL = 0x00000000"
    ATTRS{ggpio}=="GGPIO = 0x00000000"
    ATTRS{hprt0}=="HPRT0 = 0x00001005"
    ATTRS{wr_reg_test}=="Time to write GNPTXFSIZ reg 10000000 times: 360 msecs (36 jiffies)"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{hcd_frrem}=="HCD Dump Frame Remaining"
    ATTRS{mode_ch_tim_en}=="Mode Change Ready Timer Enable = 0x0"
    ATTRS{gnptxfsiz}=="GNPTXFSIZ = 0x01000306"
    ATTRS{remote_wakeup}=="Remote Wakeup Sig = 0 Enabled = 0 LPM Remote Wakeup = 0"
    ATTRS{busconnected}=="Bus Connected = 0x1"
    ATTRS{hcddump}=="HCD Dump"
    ATTRS{gotgctl}=="GOTGCTL = 0x001c0001"
    ATTRS{spramdump}=="SPRAM Dump"
    ATTRS{grxfsiz}=="GRXFSIZ = 0x00000306"
    ATTRS{gsnpsid}=="GSNPSID = 0x4f54280a"
    ATTRS{gusbcfg}=="GUSBCFG = 0x20001700"
    ATTRS{hptxfsiz}=="HPTXFSIZ = 0x02000406"
    ATTRS{devspeed}=="Device Speed = 0x0"
    ATTRS{fr_interval}=="Frame Interval = 0x1d4c"
    ATTRS{rem_wakeup_pwrdn}==""
    ATTRS{bussuspend}=="Bus Suspend = 0x0"
    ATTRS{buspower}=="Bus Power = 0x1"
    ATTRS{hnpcapable}=="HNPCapable = 0x1"
    ATTRS{rd_reg_test}=="Time to read GNPTXFSIZ reg 10000000 times: 920 msecs (92 jiffies)"
    ATTRS{enumspeed}=="Device Enumeration Speed = 0x1"
    ATTRS{inv_sel_hsic}=="Invert Select HSIC = 0x0"
    ATTRS{regoffset}=="0xffffffff"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc':
    KERNELS=="soc"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="platform"
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform':
    KERNELS=="platform"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

Answer (score 0):

If it looks like your rule is being ignored, you can try a full reload. `udevadm control --reload` doesn't always work (thanks systemd).

```
systemctl force-reload udev systemd-udevd-control.socket systemd-udevd-kernel.socket
```